# Enzyme - how to simulate holding down the shift key whilst clicking?

Tags: enzyme

I'm using Enzyme/Jest for testing my React components. How do I simulate holding down the shift key whilst clicking a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same way like you simulate normal clicking the button but with one additional parameter.

```
enzymeWrapper.find('div').simulate('click', { shiftKey: true });
```

It should also work with `altKey` and `ctrlKey`, but I haven't checked it.